# How to get list of map values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var people = [
    {
        "name": "James",
        "work": "Shake Shack"
    },
    {
        "name": "Stanley Hudson",
        "work": "IBM"
    }
]
```

Is there an easy way built into Javascript to allow me to get a list of values by their key?

For exemple if I want a list like `["Shake Shack", "IBM"]`, which is all the values in the array associated with the `work` key, how can I do?

I know how to do this manually with a loop but I'd really like to know if there's some built-in functionality in Javascript that could do this for me.

Comment: Did you see [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](/q/19590865/4642212)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
var people = [
    {
        "name": "James",
        "work": "Shake Shack"
    },
    {
        "name": "Stanley Hudson",
        "work": "IBM"
    }
]

console.log(people.map((one) => one.work))
```